# What is the best control to use to display items from a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing a website that will sell items from one of my classes. It will be linked to a SQL Server db where I will pull pricing, item name, quantity and description. If I wanted to display the items from the database in a thinkgeek fashion, what would be the best control to use so I can custimize the display to actually look ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll get the best flexibility with an asp:Repeater. This means you'll have to program more, but it will give you more flexibility.

Comment: If I use a <%#  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"itemID") %> and make a Linkbutton for a [more], how do I have asp.net know which item to go to?

Comment: You can use the linkbutton's CommandArgument property set to the itemID.

Comment: Also if you use .NET 2.o you can use <%# Eval("itemID") %> which is equivalent, but easier to type and read.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you have any technology requirements, but the ASP.Net has a new type of ASP.NET project called the [Dynamic Data project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488546.aspx). Using that project you can point to your SQL Server and generate pages to display and edit the data. Pretty easy to get up and running quickly using that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of the ASP.NET GridView & DataGrid, throw in some template fields for your images and links and what not.

Answer (score 1):

@rslite and @Bryant both have good suggestions. My initial go of the problem would probably involve creating a "Thinkgeek-esque" user control, and plopping that into a repeater for display. However, the DDP would be a good call as well. Really depends on deeper level requirements than you mention.